# Custom Ribbon Button Error: Failed to call scGetFrameValue in IFrame tag

Tags: experience-editor, speak, ribbon

I'm creating some custom ribbon buttons for the experience editor in version 10.1. I have set them up using a combination of the below guides...

https://sitecorebaek.wordpress.com/tag/speak/

https://sbhatiablogs.wordpress.com/2019/09/02/add-a-custom-button-on-experience-editor-ribbon/

https://alan-null.github.io/2016/09/hide-experience-editor-tab

So far so good, the buttons are visible and the click event is triggered in the below using the below code:

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js",
"/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.Context.js"
, "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditorProxy.js"],
function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor, ExperienceEditorContext, ExperienceEditorProxy) {

    console.log("FieldEditorCommand.js loaded...");

    Sitecore.Commands.LaunchFieldEditor =
    {
        canExecute: function (context) {
            return true;
        },
        execute: function (context) {

            try {

                console.dir(context.button);

                const rawString = context.button.attributes.name;

                if (rawString.length) {

                    const fieldsString = rawString.replace("-", "|");
                    const itemId = context.currentContext.itemId.replace("%7b", "{").replace("%7d", "}")

                    ExperienceEditorProxy._pe().postRequest('webedit:fieldeditor(command = ' + itemId + ', fields = ' + fieldsString + ', id = ' + itemId + ')', null, false)

                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log("FieldEditorCommandError", err);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

My issue is when executing the post back to Sitecore using `ExperienceEditorProxy._pe().postRequest();`, I get the following error:

> Failed to call scGetFrameValue in IFrame tag. This typically happens due to a Permission Denied exception in IE9 caused by an intricate issue with Popup and ShowModalDialog calls. Blocked a frame with origin "https://cm.ljmu.localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

The origin is always `cm.ljmu.localhost` so that's not the problem. I also read that it could be a conflict with Jquery however removing jquery from experience editor pages does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you please confirm if the error msg is from the browser dev tools ->console window

Comment: Yes it's the browser reporting it in the console (blue), not an error log (red) @AbhayDhar

Comment: I am not too familiar with SPEAK but it looks like you have a error with the CSP set on your Sitecore instance or you are returning X-FRAME-OPTIONS to DENY in http response headers